# stylish reusable web forms

Tags: css, xhtml, webforms

I'm looking for some examples of stylish web forms that can be used on any site. I've googled for "stylish web forms", but most of the examples I find are of very ornate forms that use a lots of images, which are unlikely to look good on other sites that use different color schemes. I've also found lots of examples of using CSS to layout forms, but they usually don't apply any styling to the forms to make them look good.

What I'm looking for is something in between:

- Properly laid out, e.g. labels and inputs aligned (I have no opinion on the whole "label on top or alongside" debate)
- Nicely styled, but without using images so colors can be easily changed
- Semantically valid markup, e.g. no tables or JavaScript, though I'm not fundamentalist about this (a few extra divs is OK)

**A response that points to a single example is a lot more useful than "here's a page with a million example forms, most of which don't meet your requirements".**

I realize I'm being very demanding here, so apologies and thanks!

Comment: This is a design question not a programming issue.

Comment: @Lazarus - So CSS isn't a valid topic for SO? Then you've got a lot of question-closing work in front of you!

Comment: @Lazarus - Don't be lame. This has just as much right to be here as all those CSS, usability questions, best practice and ... ahem ... "Can someone give me the jQuery code to do XXXXX please" questions. This is unsubjective and has the potential to be fruitful unlike many of the others.

Comment: I think Googling would help a lot.

Comment: While I disgree with Lazarus, I WILL say that anyone answering your question will likely just being a lot of Google work that the OP should be doing on their own.  We need a "Google that yourself" close option.

Comment: @Darmen - quote: "I've googled for "stylish web forms", but most of the examples I find are of very ornate forms that use a lots of images, which are unlikely to look good on other sites that use different color schemes"

Comment: @Arriu Sorry, didn't notices that, however, @Don can look at Uniform CSS - http://www.sprawsm.com/uni-form/

Comment: @Don, CSS may be valid (but still border line) by a request for 'stylish forms' isn't. @Aiden, since when did 'stylish' constitute an objective measure? And I fully agree that this question should be judged along with the "give me the code" questions, @Don doesn't have a specific problem with his code or the CSS he is using. He wants to make his UI look better... hire a designer!

Comment: @Lazarus The website I'm working on is for a charity that have a budget of $0, so I'm developing it for free. Therefore, there is no designer budget so I have to make do with my very limited design skills and whatever help I can get from forums like SO. I don't understand why you're so adamant that CSS questions are invalid/borderline. Prima facie, the sheer number of such open questions indicates that this is a minority opinion.

Comment: @Don, as I said above CSS is borderline, it's not programming. You might as well say that SGML, RTF or Word formatting questions are equally valid. Given that programmers often have to write the CSS I accept that CSS problems are acceptable. Questions relating to 'style' are not. I fully accept the goodness of the deed you are doing and in that I'm glad that you got answers but I just think there are better forums for this question. With regard to the number of open CSS questions, is that an indication of correctness or laxness in maintaining the objectives of SO as a programming Q&A site?

Comment: And to be strict to myself... this thread of comments should be on Meta! :)

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few good sites, with self explanatory examples and usage.

1. http://designshack.co.uk/articles/10-css-form-examples
2. [http://www.smashingmagazine.com/.../](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/)
3. http://jeffhowden.com/code/css/forms/
4. http://24ways.org/2006/showing-good-form

There are billions more online, tutorials, downloadable examples, stylesheets. To get your ideal solution **you might have to mash them together**.

Answer (score 2):

See [Prettier Accessible Forms](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/prettyaccessibleforms/).

However, as noted in [Styling form controls with CSS, revisited](http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200701/styling_form_controls_with_css_revisited/), you are going to have a lot of variation in appearance across browsers and operating systems.

These articles will show you ***how*** to build visually pleasing forms, instead of giving you a catalog of a bunch of ready made templates.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is as comprehensive as what you're asking for, but I like going with something simple like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>New customer?  Provide the following</legend>

  <label for="FirstName">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ID="FirstName" name="FirstName" />

  <label for="LastName">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" ID="LastName" name="LastName" />

  <label for="Address">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" ID="Address" name="Address" />

  <label for="City">City:</label>
  <input type="text" ID="City" name="City" />

  <label for="State">State:</label>
  <input type="text" ID="State" name="State" />

  <label for="Zip">Zip:</label>
  <input type="text" ID="Zip" name="Zip" />

  <input type="submit" Text="Submit Order" />
</fieldset>
```

Using CSS like this:

```
fieldset {
  overflow: hidden;
}

label {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 125px;
  /* If you want the labels flush along the right edge */
  padding-right: 5px;
  text-align: right;
}

input {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

/* Align the submit button under the fields */
input[type=submit] {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 135px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

That produces the layout shown in the image early [in this (completely unrelated) post](http://encosia.com/2009/11/04/using-jquery-validation-with-asp-net-webforms/).  There's a source download with the markup and CSS there too, if you don't mind ASP.NET.

Speaking to reuse, I've found that basic structure to be flexible enough to use anywhere.  For example, we used basically the same markup and CSS for this more customized contact form: http://www.thirtyfiveatlanta.com/meet/

Answer (score 1):

I really like Wufoo's forms : http://wufoo.com/examples/
I've copied and used their HTML and CSS for my own projects with good results.

Answer (score 0):

[Uni-Form](http://sprawsm.com/uni-form)

This response was posted as a comment by Darmen, but I feel it's sufficiently useful that it deserves to be promoted to a reply

Answer (score -1):

http://www.rockettheme.com/ has some pretty good templates and themes. They are generally for existing CMS systems but you could adapt them or parts of them for your own sites.

Comment: I think that site just burned their branding onto my retinas. In a bad way.

Comment: This response fits perfectly into the "here's a page with a million example forms, most of which don't meet your requirements" category I mentioned in my question

Comment: Your answer could be found in the "adapt them or parts of them" I mentioned in my response. There is some good design and interfce ideas on those themes which have gone into building some decent sites for our purposes.